# My cordova application don't want to run, I don't know why

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm developing an application in Cordova. This app should be able to capture a video when you press the capture button, and then upload it on a specific server.

But I have a problem with the capture API. When I run it on emulator or a physical device, nothing happens, and on ripple, an error is returned.

My HTML code is here

```html
      <div class="button">
                <div class="button1">
                    <button id="captureVideo" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">launch a capture</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And my `js`

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        document.getElementById("captureVideo").addEventListener("click", function () {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    });
})


function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(navigator.device.capture);
    navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, { limit: 1 });
    console.log("Record launched !");
}



// Called when capture operation is finished
function captureSuccess(mediaFiles) {
    navigator.notification.alert("Capture Success");
    /*var i, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        uploadFile(mediaFiles[i]);
    }*/
}

// Called if something bad happens
function captureError(error) {
    navigator.notification.alert("Capture failed");
    var msg = 'An error occurred during capture: ' + error.code;
    navigator.notification.alert(msg, null, 'Uh oh!');
}

// Upload files to server
/*function uploadFile(mediaFile) {
    var ft = new FileTransfer(),
        path = mediaFile.fullPath,
        name = mediaFile.name;

    ft.upload(path,
        "http://my.domain.com/upload.php",
        function (result) {
            console.log('Upload success: ' + result.responseCode);
            console.log(result.bytesSent + ' bytes sent');
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log('Error uploading file ' + path + ': ' + error.code);
        },
        { fileName: name });
}*/
```

Thanks a lot for your answer :)

As demanded, I put my code directly here instead of pastebin.

Comment: What errors occurred? Please post your on here too, I doubt people are going to help you if you can't be bothered to put code on here.

Comment: Please put the shortest amount of code needed to reproduce this issue in your question. You shouldn't be making people copy paste code from a bunch of places in order to donate their free time to help you.

Comment: Why is your click event calling the `deviceready` event handler?

Comment: 'cause I readed in the cordova's capture plugin doc that you couldn't call your capture without a deviceReady event. But maybe I'm doin' that bad.
And about error, I don't have any error occured, just, nothin' happen. I just spam my button, but the app just... do nothin'.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found ! It was cause my plugin wasn't loaded in the app.